# PHP - Object of class could not be converted to string

Tags: php

I'm trying to print a property of the simple class below. But instead i get the error above. I haven't found an answer on similar questions on here. The error triggers on this line:

```
echo "$object1 name = " . $object1->name . "<br>";
```

Using XAMPP on Windows Help?

```
<?php
    $object1 = new User("Pickle", "YouGotIt");  
    print_r($object1);
    $object1->name  = "Alice";

    echo "$object1 name = " . $object1->name . "<br>"; /* this triggers the error */

    class User
    {
        public $name, $password;

        function __construct($n, $p) { // class constructor
            $name = $n;
            $password = $p;
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two things wrong in your code,

- You're using local variables in your class constructor, not instance properties. Your constructor method should be like this:

  ```
  function __construct($n, $p) {
      $this->name = $n;
      $this->password = $p;
  }
  ```
- Now comes to your error, *Object of class could not be converted to string*. This is because of this `$object` in `echo` statement,

  ```
  echo "$object1 name = " ...
        ^^^^^^^^
  ```

  You need to escape this `$object1` with backslash, like this:

  ```
  echo "\$object1 name = " . $object1->name . "<br>";
  ```

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was the way I was  initializing the class variable.

This was my code :

```
public function __construct(User $userObj) {
    $this->$userObj = $userObj;
}
```

and I solved it by changing it to the following :

```
public function __construct(User $userObj) {
    $this->userObj = $userObj;
}
```

The line in the first snippet caused the problem : `$this->$userObj = $userObj`